# How do I use the OpenTelemetry component in Apache Camel?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel, open-telemetry

Using the [Spring Boot example from Camel](https://github.com/apache/camel-spring-boot-examples/tree/main/spring-boot), I'm trying to set up OpenTelemetry to instrument Camel.

Based on the [docs](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/others/opentelemetry.html), I chose the Spring Boot Auto-configuration option and added the dependency to my `pom.xml`.

I've also annotated the main class with `@CamelOpenTelemetry`:

```
package sample.camel;

import org.apache.camel.opentelemetry.starter.CamelOpenTelemetry;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

//CHECKSTYLE:OFF
/**
 * A sample Spring Boot application that starts the Camel routes.
 */
@CamelOpenTelemetry
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyCamelApplication {
    ...
```

I started the application with `OTEL_TRACES_EXPORTER=logging mvn spring-boot:run`.

Is this correct? I'm not seeing any console output unlike this simple OpenTelemetry [example](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/java/getting-started/#run-the-instrumented-example).

I'm not sure if Camel 3.x is supported because this [page](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/docs/supported-libraries.md) says only 2.20+ is supported but Camel's [docs](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/others/opentelemetry.html) says `Since Camel 3.5` at the top.

Comment: do you manage to find solution on this?

Comment: You need to add the OpenTelemetry Java agent: https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/others/opentelemetry.html#:~:text=by%20the%20application.-,JAVA%20AGENT,-Download%20the%20latest

Comment: @user3029642 How do I add the OpenTelemetry Java Agent in a Spring Boot application?